# Church encoding of boolean and STLC

Tags: haskell, data-kinds, church-encoding

It is often said that

```
tru t f = t
fls t f = f
```

represent True and False in the sense that "we can use those terms to perform the operation on testing the truth of a boolean value".

But that hides an important caveat in that it seems only true in the untyped lambda calculus. If I just plug those values in haskell, I can write a function :

```
tryMeOnFalse ∷  (∀ t f. t → f → t) → String
tryMeOnFalse tr = "Hi"
a' = tryMeOnFalse tru
b' = tryMeOnFalse fls  -- type error !
```

which distinguishes tru and fls at the type level. How wrong/true would it be to say that :

- in STLC `tru` and `fls` are value level witness of some promoted `'Boolean` kind, which has types `'True` and `'False`
- in STLC the (coerced) typed values `(tru :: ∀ t . t → t → t)` and `(fls ::  ∀ t . t → t → t)` represent True and False (and in untyped, well the usual)

Edit : I now realize thanks to @Daniel Wagner's answer I was thinking of Second Order Lambda Calculus and not STLC in my question.

Answer (score 4):

It is not only true in the untyped lambda calculus; but in typed calculi, one does need to be a bit careful with typing, as usual. We should define:

```
type Boolean = forall r. r -> r -> r
```

We certainly have `tru, fls :: Boolean`, and should annotate them as such.
But we do *not* have `tryMeOnFalse :: Boolean -> String`! So there is no real contradiction here.

Your comments about STLC are a bit weird, since STLC has a very different typing system. We would need separate boolean types for each result type there, since there is *no* polymorphism.

In Haskell, one can certainly define types which are inhabited only by `tru` or only by `fls` (well, each type is also inhabited by `undefined`, of course); but this is generally not very useful.

Comment: I was confusing STLC with second order typed calculus I guess. when you define `type Boolean = forall r. r -> r -> r` you are using it as well.

Comment: The typical name for "second order typed calculus" is System F, fyi